# How to remove row from mysqli table from a post href

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to remove a string from DB by a Href in a form. Why does this not work for me? The query is right, nothing happens.

```
<?php
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("cms") or die(mysql_error());

    // Get all the data from the "example" table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    echo "<table border='1'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<li class='list-group-item'>";
                echo $row['header'];
                echo "<br/>";
                echo $row['description'];
                echo "<br/>";

                echo "<form method='POST'><a href='delete.php?id=".$row['page_id']."'>Remove</a></form>";

            echo "</li>";
        }

    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms');
$id = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT page_id FROM pages");

if  (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
}

?>
```

And it still won't work. Just sends me to a blank page with no query.

Comment: You're not doing any checks to see if the query is executed without any errors, instead of REMOVE, did you try `DELETE FROM...`?

Comment: I've tried Delete function too, still won't work

Comment: There are a couple of things that irk me, why are you wrapping your `<a href ...` in a form tag if it's just a simple link? In your delete.php file your `$id` will not give you the ID as you properly intend as it contains ALL the ID's from your DB. Further more, you need to add `id=` to your href (like so: `<a href="....php?id="` - In general, your code seems to be a mess and lacks a understanding how things work.

Comment: 1) You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`. 2) If you want `get` id on delete page than change your `querystring` like `<a href='delete.php?id=".$row['page_id']."'>`. 3) Change your delete query to `mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");`
}`

Comment: Why you are put `if  (isset($_POST['id'])) {`? You pass data in `get` request not `post` request. You need to change this line to `if  (isset($_GET['id'])) {`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I will try it out.

Answer (score 3):

Change this :

```
echo "<form method='POST'><a href='delete.php?".$row['page_id']."'>Remove</a></form>";
```

to

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='delete.php'><input type='hidden' value=".$row['page_id']." name='id'/><input type='submit' value='Remove'/></form>";
```

And in delete.php

This :

```
if  (isset($_GET['id'])) {
```

To

```
if  (isset($_POST['id'])) {
```

This

```
mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
```

to

```
mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'");
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS02\Sidor\delete.php on line 7`

Comment: It still gives me the same error. Could you please write down a script to remove rows from db?

Comment: change this line mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'"); to mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'"); I update the solution.

Comment: This won't give me any errors, but the row is not deleted.

Comment: Check the returned value from query : if ($query_result = mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'") { printf("Affected rows " . mysqli_num_rows($query_result); } else { printf("error"); }